# Convention for installing libraries/headers from open source projects on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, installation, shared-libraries, header-files

I normally use Linux.  If I install libraries or headers from my package manager, they'll be installed to `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib`, respectively.  If I install them from a `Makefile` or via `CMake` or similar, they go to `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib`.  Nice and simple.

**Is there a comparable convention for installing libraries and headers on Windows?**

Comment: Nothing similar, DLL Hell is strongly avoided on an operating system with a 1-800 support phone number.  App-local deployment is the norm.

Comment: App-local deployment?

Comment: Hmm, this is not going to end up well when Google is down.  Just create your own library directories, add them to the path.